# Caught exception is null itself !

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, null

I have an ASP.NET applications. Everything was fine, but recently I get exceptions that are null themselves:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Sometimes `ex` is `null` itself !

Any idea?

Comment: Chances are it's not the exception that's null but the compiler might be optimising out some of the rest of the code which causes your exception to appear elsewhere. Can you paste any of your actual code?

Comment: Also, have you narrowed down the issue to something consistent that is happening when you get the null ex (or null ex.Message)?

Comment: `ex` is `null`. I put there a `Break Point` and I'm sure it is `ex`.

Comment: It is completely impossible for that to happen, unless you write `ex = null;` beforehand.

Comment: Where did you put the breakpoint? if in 'catch' line then hover the mouse pointer you might actually get null. You need to run the codes inside the catch statement to reference the exception to ex.

Comment: Did you put the breakpoint on the catch line? If you did then ex will be null since it hasn't actually run that piece of code yet. Put the breakpoint on the Logger line then look at the value of ex.

Comment: @Mathhew: You right. It was the compiler. I should ask it in another question why sometimes (without any change) debugger says that a module has optimized.

Comment: How did you address it? I just encountered the same problem. Here is a screen shot. http://www.flickr.com/photos/7200684@N02/7521732858/in/photostream

Comment: Hope my answer to this quest might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508670/731894

Answer (score 64, accepted):

For anyone ending up here, I've found an instance where this is possible (If only detectable in the debugger). VS2013 Update 4.

### Broken:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (WebException ex) // <- both variables are named 'ex'
{
    Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex) // <- this 'ex' is null
{
    Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The solution is to name your exception variables differently.

### Fixed:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (WebException webEx) // <- all good in the hood
{
    Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + webEx.Message); // <-
}
catch (Exception ex) // <- this 'ex' correctly contains the exception
{
    Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I experience the same issue with VS2013 Update 4. have you already reported this bug to microsoft? I've tried to, but it seems hard to create a repro. When i add a simple `throw new InvalidOperationException()` into the `try` clause the issue does not occur.

Comment: I've reported the issue on MS Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1116170). You're welcome to upvote it.

Comment: Same problem and fix with Visual Studio 2013 Update 5.

Comment: This is the right answer... i have suffered from it. The issue still exists in VS2015.

Comment: for me, there is only one catch block. still, I got the issue. not sure what's wrong with the code?

Comment: The issue also currently could be observed in Jetbrainbs Rider IDE.

Comment: I have just run into something similar in VS 2019. I have an ASP.NET web app where a controller action has two separate try/catch blocks. When the first block doesn't catch the error, but the second block does, and both define the catch as catch(Exception ex), then ex is always null in the second block. Renaming the second block's ex variable solved the problem.

Comment: This still happens in VS 2019 16.6.3. I have a WebSocketException catch block followed by a System.Exception catch block, and if they are both named "ex", the System.Exception catch will always be null.

Comment: still in 16.9.2

Comment: Running VS 2022 Version 17.0.1 and this is still an issue :facepalm:

Comment: Still an issue here.....

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the cause was a `StackOverflowException`. Such exceptions normally don't reach the `catch` block at all, but this time, for some reason I don't understand, it did reach the `catch` block, but the exception was `null`.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into an issue where someone was passing `ex.InnerException` to a method, where `ex` was the root. Since the parameter was also called `ex` it led to some confusion in the debugger when I looked at the originally caught exception. This was likely the result of some careless refactoring.

e.g.:

```
public void MyMethod(string input)
{
    try {
        Process(input);
    } catch (Exception ex) { // <- (2) Attempting to view ex here would show null
        _logger.log(ex);
        LogInner(ex.InnerException);
    }
}

private void LogInner(Exception ex)
{
    _logger.log(ex); // <- (1) NullReferenceExeption thrown here
    if(ex.InnerException != null)
        LogInner(ex.InnerException);
}
```

This was refactored as such:

```
public void MyMethod(string input)
{
    try {
        Process(input);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LogExceptionTree(ex);
    }
}

private void LogExceptionTree(Exception exception)
{
    _logger.log(exception);
    if(exception.InnerException != null)
        LogExceptionTree(exception.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue.  The outer exception was named `Exception ex` and the inner was too and returning null.

Answer (score -1):

That cannot happen.

If you `throw null`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` from the `throw`; the exception in the `catch` block can never be `null`.

You have something else that's `null`.

Comment: +1 Stack Overflow questions make me test the darndest things!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's possible to throw `null` *somehow*. I think it's already possible to throw classes not derived from `Exception`. But I'd be surprised if `catch(Exception ex)` would catch such a `null` exception.

Comment: Nope. It's just like SLaks said: If you throw a null reference, you get a `NullReferenceException`. I just tried myself, too.

Comment: I don't `throw` the exception. Also I put a `Break Point` there and `ex` was null. Maybe it's not a `CLR` issue and it's the `Visual Studio 2010`.

Comment: Recently I used custom exceptions in `web.config` under `httpErrors>` and put a `<clear/>` as the first node and then `<error statusCode="400" responseMode="Redirect" path="Error.aspx?Code=400"/>` but I commented it after this problem.

Comment: @Xaqron - We are not saying *you* are throwing a null exception. We're saying it's not possible to do so. Also, that area of `web.config` has nothing at all to do with your problem, in all likelihood.

Comment: It's about Java. But you cat found it interesting http://www.adarshr.com/papers/npe

Comment: This definitely CAN happen. Have experienced it myself.

Comment: We just saw this not ten minutes ago. Renaming the second catch variable made it go away. This is just... wow. How have we never run into this before. I name ALL my exception catch variables "ex", and I've never seen this before today, but we can absolutely 100% reproduce this.

Answer (score -1):

This may happen when the Exception is an AggregateException.

Comment: ..ok? Under what circumstances? An `AggregateException` is still an `Exception` so it should not itself be null.

Answer (score -2):

I met the same problem, and the reason is: the exception is a NullReferenceException, so you can not use ex.Message, and you should try the flowing:

```
try
 {     // do something } 

catch (NullReferenceException)
{
  Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: Null reference");
}

catch (Exception ex) 
{     
  Logger.Log("Error while tried to do something. Error: " + ex.Message); 
}
```

Comment: You are wrong.  A `NullReferenceException` will not have a null `Message`.