# Xamarin forms local store exception when insert item

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Almost everything works great except one form that doesn't save some data to Azure database and I can't catch any info about exception i.e exception instance is `null` when break point stop in exception of type `MobileServiceLocalStoreException`. I checked the initialization of the local store and there is no problem with it, so what could be the reason behind this exception.

```
public async Task<T> CreateItemAsync(T item)
{
    try
    { 
        await table.InsertAsync(item);
    }
    catch(MobileServiceLocalStoreException ex)
    { // here exception occurd
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: How does your code look? Without a proper exception and the code it's really hard to tell what went wrong. Could you add a `Debug.WriteLine(e)` in the exception handler?

Comment: As you see @PaulKertscher here ,the ex instance of local store exception is null.

Comment: I followed adrianHall online book to work with azure.

Comment: I can't see, but - yeah - if you are saying it. Are you running your app in Debug or release mode? Does the current code throw a `NullReferenceException` or does `Debug.WriteLine` write out anything?

Comment: Is the build up to date?

Comment: I'm running my app in debug mode, it doesn't throw any thing,firstly it was crash and close app, now it stops in that catch code but without any information about error.

Comment: Yes, and it save different data from other forms except this one which its code is very similar to other forms code.

Comment: Where did you put your breakpoint? If you are putting it before the body of the catch clause `ex` will be null in any case. Does it write something to the debug output? Do you know where to find the debug output?

Comment: I put the breakpoint inside catch body, and I don't see any debug output in output window

Comment: And `ex` is still `null`? This is really weird. Have you checked if your build is up to date? Do you conincidentially have any field variable that is named `ex`? I don't know how `ex` should be `null`, tbh.

Comment: It must be occur in other forms when I try to insert new items  if the build is not up to date. There is no any field with name in the item of type T ex

Comment: Could you try to rename of of the `ex`es to something else? There was a bug that caused the very behavior you are describing (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634417/caught-exception-is-null-itself) - anyway, I don't know if this bug still exists)

Comment: Thanks @PaulKertscher the exception message appeared and it saying "An insert operation on the item is already in the queue."